# Read JSON data from Blob where the files are stored inside date folders which auto increments everyday

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hdfs blob stores the json data in the below format on a daily basis. I will need to read the json data using spark.read.json() on a day wise. Ex: Today i want to read day=01 day's files and tomorrow i want to read day=02 day's files. Is there a logic i can write in Scala which auto increments the date consider month and year also. Any help would me much appreciated.

```
/signals/year=2019/month=08/day=01
/signals/year=2019/month=08/day=01/*****.json
/signals/year=2019/month=08/day=01/*****.json

/signals/year=2019/month=08/day=02

/signals/year=2019/month=08/day=02/*****_.json
/signals/year=2019/month=08/day=02/*****_.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like data stored in partitioned format, and for read only one date such function can be used:

```
  def readForDate(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int): DataFrame = {
    spark.read.json("/signals")
    .where($"year" === year && $"month" === month && $"day" === day)
  }
```

For use this function, take current date and split on parts, with regular Scala code, not related to Spark.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any relation between current date and the date you want to process the JSON file, you can get the current date (you can add/minus any number of days) using below Scala code and use it in your Spark application as @pasha701 suggested.

```
scala> import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
scala> import java.time.LocalDateTime

scala> val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd") // you can get the Year and Month like this.
scala> val now = LocalDateTime.now()
scala> println(dtf.format(now))
02

scala> println(dtf.format(now.plusDays(2))) // Added two days on the current date
04
```

Just a thought: If you are using Azure's Databricks then  you can run shell command in notebook to get the current day (again if there is any relation on the partition's files you are trying to fetch with the current date) using "%sh" command.

Comment: Thanks guys for your time and efforts Praveen Nag and @pasha701. Your answers helped me a lot.

Comment: @Anil Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help any of you in future. Below code helps to read the data available in blob where the files are stored inside date folders which auto increments everyday. I wanted to read the data of previous day's data so adding now.minusDays(1)

```
    val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val now = LocalDateTime.now()
    val date = dtf.format(now.minusDays(1))

    val currentDateHold = date.split("-").toList
    val year = currentDateHold(0)
    val month = currentDateHold(1)
    val day = currentDateHold(2)

    val path = "/signals/year="+year+"/month="+month+"/day="+day

    // Read JSON data from the Azure Blob`enter code here`
    var initialDF = spark.read.format("json").load(path)
```